# Configuring native Point PostgreSQL Type in Doctrine2

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Trying to do the same as here, with Postgres:

http://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/02/19/using-spatial-data-in-doctrine-2/

I have a problem with the "convertToDatabaseValue" function 
(see here : http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types)

My Custom Type :

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class PointType extends Type
{
const POINT = 'point';

public function getSqlDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return 'POINT';
}

public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return new Point($value[0],$value[1]);
}

public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return "'".$value->getLongitude().','.$value->getLatitude()."'";
}

public function getName()
{
    return self::POINT;
}
}
```

Manualy, I can insert this Point with following SQL :

```
INSERT INTO points (pointtype,name,score) VALUES ('2.43145,42.84214',"My Place",3241)
```

But doctrine DBAL, creates following code :

```
'INSERT INTO points (pointtype,name,score) VALUES (?,?,?)' with params ["'2.43145,42.84214'","My Place",3241]
```

-> My Point is interpreted as a string ...

Can I avoid that ?

CAUTION: I don't want to use PostGIS, juste native Points from PostgreSQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you need to return just string and Doctrine will automatically wrap it with quotes. Try this code:

```
public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return $value->getLongitude().','.$value->getLatitude();
}
```

It will generate you next SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO points (pointtype,name,score) VALUES ("2.43145,42.84214","My Place",3241)
```

Comment: I tried it but PostgreSQL want simple quotes, it doesn't work with double quotes.

Comment: Did you set up your doctrine to use `pdo_pgsql` in your `parameters.yml`?

Comment: Yes, everything works, but this custom type is custom ...
And as it is, it doesn't work

Comment: try to `echo $platform->getName(); exit();` before `return` statement in `convertToDatabaseValue(...)`. What is in the output?

Comment: I receive "postgresql"

Comment: It is very strange behaviour. I think you should create ticket in Doctrine issue tracker.

Comment: I tested Michael's solution and it inserted perfectly for me. I used a Doctrine entity with a "point" type and it created a new row in the database without any problems.

Comment: Doctrine creates following SQL :

'INSERT INTO Addresses (id, location) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [2,"2.352,48.857"]


Then I have this error :

null value in column "location" violates not-null constraint

Comment: I updated the inital question because Doctrine creates a SQL with "with params" ...